# Is it okay to finish an informal letter with "that's it for now"?

Tags: phrase-usage, writing

> **That's it for now,** give my love to your father.
>
> Write back soon.
>
> Yours,
>   X

Someone has said that it is a mistake and one should write 'That's *all* for now...' Is it okay to finish an informal letter this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can finish an informal letter any way you please.

If you are fussy about the layout, you might start a new line for

**Give my love to your father**

and possibly add something to **Yours**

**Yours fondly/affectionately...**

and be sure that you wish to convey your love only to a single (living) parent (your father) rather than (both) your parents or your mother and father.

In short, there are no rules concerning ways to finish informal letters.

Comment: Yes, thanks but can you comment on the phrase in bold? Someone has said that it is a mistake and one should write 'That's _all_ for now...'

Comment: The "Yours" sounds a bit formal to me. I would just put my name, but as you said you can pretty much anything you want. Cheerio!

Comment: @Aer You may safely use **it** or **all** in an informal setting. Don't be too bothered about what **someone** says.

Comment: @Aer most native speakers don't care about grammar in informal settings so long as the intended message comes through clearly and without unintended implications, and there's no particular reason you should either.

Comment: @Darael thanks; I understand this fact but there are some cases—especially when a non-native speaker should pass the English exam—which requires attention to grammar rules.

Answer (score 1):

"That's it for now" is synonymous with "That's all I have [to say, to report] for now".  Perfectly legit.